# Javascript: Determine if all of the elements in the array are keys in the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I am trying to figure out if all of the elements in an array are keys in the object.

```
var obj = { name: 'Computer', cost: '$1,000' };
var myArray = [ 'name', 'cost', 'bio' ]; //another example would be var myArray = [];
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
if (myArray[x] in obj)
  {
     return true;
  }
}
```

How can I check if all of the elements in an array are keys in the object?

Comment: btw, it doesnt affect the end result but its more common for people to use `i` as the index variable instead of `x`.

Comment: @hugomg—it's a hangover from Fortran, where undeclared variables with a name starting with a letter in the range *i* to *n* inclusive were typed as integers (I guess *I* to *N* originally). But yes, a very common practice in most languages.;-)

Comment: @RobG: The fortran typing rules were most likely that way to support the already existing practice of using i,j,k,m,n as integers in math notation: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want, this might do the trick:

```
function hasKeys(obj, keys) {
    for (var i=0; i != keys.length; ++i) {
        if (!(keys[i] in obj))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

One subtlety you need to ask yourself: do you want to know if the object has the keys directly (i.e. not somewhere in its prototype stack?) If so, then replace `keys[i] in obj` with `obj.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])`

Comment: A good answer but I would recommend making this a regular function instead of overriding Object.prototype.

Comment: I have tested this, and it is now working. I am trying to understand the tester and increment you used in the for loop. Why did you use `i != keys.length` versus `i < keys.length`? Also why did you use `++i` versus `i++`?

Comment: It's a habit from C++. When you get down to assembly level, a straight equality comparison like `==` or `!=` is _slightly_ faster than ordering comparisons like `<`, `<=`, `>=`, or `>`. Similarly, in C++ `++i` is _slightly_ faster than `i++` because the latter has to do the increment then remember the previous value of `i`. I doubt you'll have any need to care about those differences.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 3):

Do it the other way around. If you find someone in the array who is NOT in the object then you return false. If you reach the end of the loop then you return true because all the keys were in the object.

Comment: That makes sense. I am just not sure how to implement that. How would I determine if an element in the array is NOT in the object?

Comment: You can use the `!` operator to negate a boolean test. So `!(a in b)` tests if a is not in b. Alternatively, you could have put your logic inside an `else clause (although its a bit ugly to have an else clause if the main if clause is empty)

Comment: I have added the ! operator but it is still not working. I suspect I am doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
function hasKeys(obj, keys) {
    return keys.every(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj));
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every states, "The every method executes the provided callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a falsy value (a value that becomes false when converted to a Boolean). **If such an element is found, the every method immediately returns false.** Otherwise, if callback returned a true value for all elements, every will return true. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Very nice solution. I look forward to using this when I learn about functions.

Comment: Very nice solution +1, except it doesn't work. Did you test it? The problem is that `every` will call `Object#hasOwnProperty` with no `this`. You need to do `keys.every(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj))`.

Comment: @torazaburo I didn't. Will make the change.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) makes for a clean solution.

```
// object in question
var obj = { ... };

// keys that need to be present in the object
var keys = [ ... ];

// iterate through the whitelist until we find a key that doesn't exist in the object. If all exist, that means Array.some() is false.
var valid = !keys.some(function(key) {
    return !obj.hasOwnProperty(key);
});
```

An alternative solution would be using a similar concept, but with [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). It is to note that this will generally be slower because it always has to touch every element in the whitelist.

```
// iterate through the whitelist, making sure the object has each key.
var valid = keys.every(obj.hasOwnProperty);
```

Comment: I am not yet too comfortable with callback functions but this is indeed a clean solution.

Comment: I do not understand your comment about `Array#every` having to visit every element in what you call the whitelist (the list of required keys). It will stop as soon as it finds the first one not present in the object and return false. In general, `every(predicate)` is exactly equivalent to `!some(!predicate)`, so all you've done is introduce two additional negation operations.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be expressed in terms of set inclusion: does the set of property keys completely include the array of required keys? So we can write it as

```
includes(Object.keys(obj), arr)
```

So now we just need to write `includes`.

```
function includes(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr2.every(function(key) {
        return contains(arr1, key);
    }
}
```

For `contains`, we could use Underscore's `_.contains`, or just write it ourselves:

```
function contains(arr, val) {
    return arr.indexOf(val) !== -1;
}
```

If we are interested in conciseness at the possible expense of readability, we could shorten our definition of `includes` to use `Function#bind` instead of the anonymous function:

```
function includes(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr2.every(contains.bind(0, arr1));
}
```

Now we have functions we can use for other things, instead of mixing up the two different aspects of the problem--the keys of an object, and set inclusion. If we really want to write an all-in-one function, it becomes the somewhat more readable:

```
function hasMany(obj, arr) {
    return arr.every(_.contains.bind(0, Object.keys(obj));
}
```

If we want more readability, like we were writing a novel:

```
function object_has_required_keys(object, required_keys) {

    var object_keys = Object.keys(object);

    function key_is_present(key) {
        return object_keys.indexOf(key) !== -1;
    }

    return required_keys.every(key_is_present);
}
```

#### Underscore's `_.intersection`

If we're lazy (or smart), we could use Underscore's [_.intersection](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) to implement `includes`:

```
function includes(arr1, arr2) {
    return _.intersection(arr1, arr2).length === arr2.length;
}
```

The idea is to take the intersection, and if the first array includes the second entirely, then the intersection will contain all the elements of the second array, which we can check by comparing their lengths.

#### Using ES6 sets

Thinking ahead to ES6, we could implement `include` using its [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which ought to be faster:

```
function includes(arr1, arr2) {
    var set = new Set(arr1);
    return arr2.every(Set.prototype.has.bind(set));
}
```